# Persistent storage in IntelliJ plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, persistent-storage

I am developing an IntelliJ plugin, and I would like to store some settings information as a string. How am I able to store it? I found that `PersistentStateComponent<T>` is for this purpose, but I didn't find any working and simple use of this class.

Could you please provide some info , how am I able to create a class with only one String argument and methods like:

```
     Void Save(String value)
    {
       //save SettingsAsString
    {

     String Load()
    {
       //Do something
       return savedSettingsAsString
    }
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

Implement the `applicationService` extension point

`<applicationService serviceImplementation="com.sylvanaar.idea.Lua.options.LuaApplicationSettings"/>`

Then the settings implementation is pretty much boilerplate, you just create fields on the settings class for all the settings you want to store.

```
public class LuaApplicationSettings implements PersistentStateComponent<LuaApplicationSettings> {
    public boolean INCLUDE_ALL_FIELDS_IN_COMPLETIONS = false;
    public boolean SHOW_TAIL_CALLS_IN_GUTTER = true;
    public boolean ENABLE_TYPE_INFERENCE = true;

    @Override
    public LuaApplicationSettings getState() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadState(LuaApplicationSettings state) {
         XmlSerializerUtil.copyBean(state, this);
    }

    public static LuaApplicationSettings getInstance() {
        return ServiceManager.getService(LuaApplicationSettings.class);
    }
}
```